# What do "#@+" & "#@-" strings mean in the comments?

Tags: magento2, php, code, code-generation, code-analysis

I see a lot of "#@+" & "#@-" strings in the comments of the some Magento 2 classes.
`\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AttributeMetadataInterface`

```
interface AttributeMetadataInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\MetadataObjectInterface
{
    /**#@+
     * Constants used as keys of data array
     */
    const ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'attribute_code';
    ...
    const IS_SEARCHABLE_IN_GRID = 'is_searchable_in_grid';
    /**#@-*/
    ...
}
```

What is the purpose of these markers?

Answer (score 14):

Those characters are used to **declare a PHPDoc DocBlock template**:

> The purpose of a DocBlock template is to reduce redundant typing. For
>   instance, if a large number of class variables are private, one would
>   use a DocBlock template to mark them as private. DocBlock templates
>   simply augment any normal DocBlocks found in the template block.
>
> A DocBlock template is distinguished from a normal DocBlock by its
>   header.

```
/**#@+
 *
 */
```

> The text that marks this as a DocBlock template is "/**#@+" - all 6
>   characters must be present. DocBlock templates are applied to all
>   documentable elements until the ending template marker:

```
/**#@-*/
```

> Note that all 8 characters must appear as "/**#@-*/" in order for
>   phpDocumentor to recognize them as a template.

More information can be found here: http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/how-to-use-docblock-templates-in-phpdoc

Some explanations are also available on the official Magento documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/docblock-standard-general.html

Answer (score 6):

If there is declaration of multiple consecutive elements of same type, the same contents of DocBlock may be relevant to all of them. In this case individual DocBlocks for those elements they may be replaced by a DocBlock template.

DocBlock template consists of two DocBlock comments:

Starting comment is before first element of the group, distinguished using #@+ and formatted as follows:

```
/**#@+
 *
 */
```

Ending comment is after the last element of the group, distinguished using #@- and formatted as follows:`/**#@-*/`

For example, declaration of multiple class constants or attributes:

```
class Mage_Core_Model_Layout extends Varien_Simplexml_Config
{
    /**#@+
     * Supported layout directives
     * @var string
     */
    const TYPE_BLOCK = 'block';
    const TYPE_CONTAINER = 'container';
    /**#@-*/

    /**#@+
     * Scheduled structure elements operations
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $scheduledMoves   = array();
    protected $scheduledRemoves = array();
    /**#@-*/
```

Reference [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/docblock-standard-general.html)